# How to generate insert scripts from existing table in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In snowflake there is an existing table with 50 records but I need to get the sql insert scripts to make some changes and move into another environment.

Is there any way to get the sql insert scripts Snowflake.

I had tried but didn't got any solution.
I am only getting DDLs thru getddl().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this and then download the resuts from the snowflake console

```
WITH CUST_TABLE AS(
SELECT C_CUSTKEY, C_NAME FROM LOB1_DB.LOB1_SCHEMA.CUSTOMER)
SELECT 'INSERT INTO ' || 'CUSTOMER VALUES(' || C_CUSTKEY ||',"'|| C_NAME || '");'
FROM CUST_TABLE;
```

Comment: I will try to make a S.P to have a generic solution.